# BETA iOS9 deployment to test devices

Tags: ios9, xcode7

Can I download iOS9 + Xcode 7 and still deploy test apps to devices that use the current version of iOS?

Sorry for the relatively stupid question, I'm a new developer and not sure how it has worked in the past and I can't find anything on the developer site....

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just looked into this: **Availability
You should always use the latest SDK to get access to the latest features, documentation, and API changes, but sometimes your app needs to run on an older OS. Swift 2.0 has built-in availability checking to make it easy to build the best possible app for each target OS version. The compiler will give you an error when using an API too new for your minimum target OS, and a new keyword lets you wrap blocks of code in a conditional version check to run only on specific OS releases.** Assuming that it can be used...

Comment: here is step which guides how ios app can be installed without provisioning profile :http://stackoverflow.com/a/30885089/3400991

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With any iOS version, it depends on the minimum requirements for the app you're making.  If you use any code that requires iOS 9 or set your projects requirements to iOS 9, it won't run on iOS 8 devices.  But if you make an app designed for iOS 8 or earlier, it will run on those devices, even if you make it using Xcode 7.

But since you're a new developer, keep in mind: **anything made with Xcode 7 can't be submitted to the App Store until Xcode 7 is officially released**, likely this fall.  That applies to *everything*, regardless of target OS.

So if you want to release your app this summer, make your app with the current version of Xcode, and just use the new Xcode 7 beta to experiment, and to develop future releases.

Comment: Sorry, 1 more, question. Would Xcode 7/swift2 allow us to deploy to test devices even though we can't submit to the app store? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rinyfo4 If you make an app that requires iOS 9, you'll need a device that is running the iOS 9 beta to run it.  But if you have one, you should be fine, and if you aim for lower than iOS 9, you'll be able to run it on any device that meets the requirements.  Keep in mind, though: iOS 9 is in beta for a reason.  If you put it on your one-and-only personal iPhone, there may be bugs or problems that can be quite frustrating for you between now and release.  (That happened to me with iOS 7, and I only put beta OS's on secondary devices now.)

Comment: Good point... I'll just keep both for experimentation in that case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rinyfo4  Happy to help!  And remember: you always have the iOS Simulator that comes with Xcode.  So even if you don't have an iPad Mini running iOS 9, or whatever, you can test and develop using that for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Sumple rule set your deployment target to lower & it will be supported in all higher version os.

But before launching on store better you review them in those environment because with higher version certain API have changed few of them might depreciated & replaced with others.

As per current situation make base 7.0 as deployment target & your app will work on majority of devices/users.