# Xcode7 beta no provisioning is it right?

Tags: xcode, ios9

When I watch the WWDC 2015 video,I got a message:you can run on the device without provisioning.But when I use the Xcode7 beta for test,I must choose a provisioning for my iphone4s (iOS7.1) and the iPad（iOS9 beta）no need.Any one Know why?Is it only support iOS9 without provisioning?

Comment: Yeah I heard about [free provisioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015242-SW10) but not sure how that works

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3

Comment: Thank you Inder Kumar Rathore.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap/32249026#32249026

Answer (score 14):

Yeh now anyone can test `iOS` app on physical device so no need to enroll in developer program . Here is step for running `iOS` application without using provisioning profile : [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3)

- In `Xcode`, first of all add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences.
- In the project navigator, select the project and your target to display the project editor.
- Click General and choose your name from the Team pop-up menu.
- Connect the device to your Mac and choose your device from the Scheme toolbar menu.
- Below the Team pop-up menu, click Fix Issue. Xcode creates a free provisioning profile for you and the warning text under the Team pop-up menu disappears.
- Click the Run button.

  Xcode installs the app on the device before launching the app.

Hope it helps .

Comment: I know what you mean，Thank you for your answer,but it is not new in Xcode7,the provisioning is made by Xcode,not the free provisioning.

Comment: yeah but in the above apple developer  link it is clearly mention  "Xcode creates a free provisioning profile for you and the warning text under the Team pop-up menu disappears." when we configured apple id and select team and then fix issue .

Comment: I'm sorry,SKT.You are right.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3

Comment: dont be sorry . no issue .. then make it right answer so that other get help from this .

Comment: It is true..  I am able to run my app on my iphone with free developer account. Same is mentioned in  apple key note video too.

Comment: unfortunatly when i hit button Fix Issue my iphone 5s isn't being "registered" i get"a message saying "No Devices Registerd Creating a provisioning profile requires one or more devices to be registered with your team. Connect a device to your Mac to add it to your team" But my iphone is connected, any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: nevermind i forgot to choose my device from the product destination toolbar menu before i hit Fix Issue

Comment: Check this answer for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap/32249026#32249026

Answer (score -1):

Yes, one of the new features of Xcode 7 Beta is that anyone can now load apps onto their device without having to be a member of the developer program.

in this blog，there are the steps：
http://bouk.co/blog/sideload-iphone/

Hope it helps.